# How do I make youtube api call to get categories according to given region and api key?

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I added this class to form1:

```
public class YoutubeApiResponse
        {
            public string kind { get; set; }
            public string etag { get; set; }
            public string nextPageToken { get; set; }
            public PageInfo pageInfo { get; set; }
            public List<Item> items { get; set; }
        }
```

The var Item not exist in the List

Then in form1 constructor I did:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("search?q=manam&type=video&order=relevance&part=snippet&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSyA4GZFAgfvsAItwFRmnAZvbTHoDeyunf2k").Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var youtubeResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync < YoutubeApiResponse().Result();
                }
            }
```

The api key is not valid api key, I just changed some letters random.

And in this part i'm getting error on the line:

```
var youtubeResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync < YoutubeApiResponse().Result();
```

YoutubeApiResponse not exist so I changed it to YoutubeApiResponse but this doesn't have the Result property.

Another error on this line: Error   2   The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

And:

Error   1   'System.Net.Http.HttpContent' does not contain a definition for 'ReadAsAsync' and no extension method 'ReadAsAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpContent' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And the link that I'm using should be used to get the categories according to given region is: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&regionCode=IL&key=AIzaSyBgc1Gx-0tHbWp6-SWE0sQarpc6nGLtttt

In this example region code IL and api key.

I just not sure how to use it in my c# code.
This is my form1 code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;

using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.GData.Extensions.MediaRss;

namespace Youtube_Manager
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        string err1 = ""
        string userName = "someone@gmail.com";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("search?q=manam&type=video&order=relevance&part=snippet&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSyA4GZFAgfvsAItwFRmnAZvbTHoDeyunf2k").Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var youtubeResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync < YoutubeApiResponse().Result();
                }
            }

            UserCredential credential;
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"D:\C-Sharp\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\bin\Debug\client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore("YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;
            }
            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });
            var video = new Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
            video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22";
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public";
            var filePath = @"C:\Users\bout0_000\Videos\test.mp4";//@"E:\video.mp4"; 
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {

                const int KB = 0x400;
                var minimumChunkSize = 256 * KB;

                var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video,
                    "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
                videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged +=
                    videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
                videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived +=
                    videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
                // The default chunk size is 10MB, here will use 1MB.
                videosInsertRequest.ChunkSize = minimumChunkSize * 4;
                videosInsertRequest.Upload();
            }
        }

        private static void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video obj)
        {

        }

        private static void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(IUploadProgress obj)
        {

        }

        private async Task Run()
        {
            UserCredential credential = null;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(@"D:\C-Sharp\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\bin\Debug\client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                try
                {
                    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the authenticated 
                        // user's account, but not other types of account access.
                        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly },
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
                    );
                }
                catch (Exception errrr)
                {
                    err1 = errrr.ToString();
                }
            }

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
            });

            var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("snippet,contentDetails");
            channelsListRequest.ForUsername = userName;
            var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

            foreach (var channel in channelsListResponse.Items)
            {
                var uploadsListId = channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;
                var nextPageToken = "";
                while (nextPageToken != null)
                {
                    var playlistRequest = youtubeService.Playlists.List("id,snippet,contentDetails,status,player");
                    playlistRequest.Id = uploadsListId;
                    playlistRequest.MaxResults = 50;
                    playlistRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;
                    var playlistListResponse = await playlistRequest.ExecuteAsync();
                    if (playlistListResponse.Items.Count > 0)
                        MessageBox.Show(playlistListResponse.Items[0].Snippet.Title);

                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public class YoutubeApiResponse
        {
            public string kind { get; set; }
            public string etag { get; set; }
            public string nextPageToken { get; set; }
            public PageInfo pageInfo { get; set; }
            public List<Item> items { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Using the part to get the categories according to given region id and add the categories later to a ComboBox as items that's i don't understand how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mixing some things up.

Authenticate using a public API key:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// using Public APi key
        /// Documentation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clientId">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="clientSecret">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="userName">A string used to identify a user.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static YouTubeService AuthenticateOauth(string apiKey)
        {
            try
            {
                YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(new YouTubeService.Initializer()
                {
                    ApiKey = apiKey,
                    ApplicationName = "YouTube Data API Sample",
                });
                return service;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                return null;
            }

        }
```

Authenticate

```
 var service = Authentication.AuthenticateOauth("xxxxx8wFajmmARCqp7YdqkLmd1XYx7c");
```

Make a request:

```
    var searchListRequest = service.Search.List("snippet");
    searchListRequest.Q = "Google"; // Replace with your search term.
    searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;

    // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
    var searchListResponse = searchListRequest.Execute();

    List<string> videos = new List<string>();
    List<string> channels = new List<string>();
    List<string> playlists = new List<string>();

    // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
    // matching videos, channels, and playlists.
    foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
    {
        switch (searchResult.Id.Kind)
        {
            case "youtube#video":
                videos.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.VideoId));
                break;

            case "youtube#channel":
                channels.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.ChannelId));
                break;

            case "youtube#playlist":
                playlists.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.PlaylistId));
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

code ripped from sample project Google-dotnet-samples [Youtube](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/YouTube)

**Update videoCatagories  example:**

```
 var videoCatagories = service.VideoCategories.List("snippet");
 videoCatagories.RegionCode = "IL";
 var result = videoCatagories.Execute();
```

Comment: This is working great. I also wanted in my question to get all the categories according to a given region id so the user will be able to select a category from a List when he upload a video. The uploading video in my code in my question is working the problem is now it set to category "22" and instead i want to get a list of all categories names and id's first according to a given region id so instead "22" i will select a name of category in a combobox and it will set the id. That's what i'm not sure how to do yet.

Comment: have you tried looking at the service.VideoCategories method? try that

Comment: See second answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858991/how-do-i-know-what-category-id-is-what-category-name-when-uploading-a-video-to-y/30868425#30868425)